# Creation of new table fails with error message "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I have 2 SQL statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries
(
    country_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country varchar(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patients
(
    p_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    p_fname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    p_mname varchar(10) NULL,
    p_lname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL,
    sex SET ('Male','Female'),
    phone_num_mobile varchar(10) NULL,
    phone_num_res varchar(7) NULL,
    phone_num_office varchar(7) NULL,
    email varchar(75) NULL,
    addr_house varchar(10) NULL,
    addr_street1 varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    addr_street2 varchar(45) NULL,
    addr_street3 varchar(45) NULL,
    addr_city varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    addr_country varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    occupation varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    married BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(addr_country) REFERENCES countries(country)
);
```

The first one executes successfully and the second one, which assigns a foreign key to the previous table, fails to execute with the message 'Foreign key constraint incorrectly formed'. I have also tried altering the second query's foreign key field(addr_country) to have the same name as that of the 'countries' table(country) but it were top no avail.

Can anyone please explain me what's going on and suggest me with a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why aren't you referencing to the country_id field ? You should add the key CONSTRAINT in front, CONSTRAINT 'fk_patient_country' FOREIGN KEY(addr_country) REFERENCES countries(country)

Comment: in your patients table you should have country_id instead of the country, it's a better design practice

Comment: Recommend you use the 2-char standard country codes, not a 4-byte INT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key in MariaDB can only reference either a primary key in another table or a unique key.  In this case, the `countries` table already has a primary key, so you can create a unique key on the `country` column.

Try putting a unique constraint on the `country` column in the `countries` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries
(
    country_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country varchar(45) NOT NULL
    UNIQUE KEY(country)
);
```

Late edit: As the commentors mentioned, you might want to just reference the `country_id` primary key instead of the country name.  Since no two countries in the world have the same name, either might work in practice.